# Comparar duas hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

Olá, eu preciso comprar os valores de 2 Hashmaps. Estou fazendo uma Image Matcher usando quantidade de cores iguais, usando esse código, mas nao sei como posso compara-las.

```
public static double DoesMatch2(BufferedImage arg0, BufferedImage arg1){
    HashMap<Color, Integer> pixMap0 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Color, Integer> pixMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    for (int x = arg0.getWidth()-1; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (int y = arg0.getHeight()-1; y >= 0; y--) {
            int clr=  arg0.getRGB(x,y); 
            int  red   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue  =  clr & 0x000000ff;
            Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            if(pixMap0.containsKey(color)){
                pixMap0.put(color, pixMap0.get(color)+1);
            }else{
                pixMap0.put(color, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = arg1.getWidth()-1; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (int y = arg1.getHeight()-1; y >= 0; y--) {
            int clr=  arg1.getRGB(x,y); 
            int  red   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue  =  clr & 0x000000ff;
            Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            if(pixMap1.containsKey(color)){
                pixMap1.put(color, pixMap0.get(color)+1);
            }else{
                pixMap1.put(color, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pixMap1.equals(pixMap0)` não funciona?

Comment: Não, eu precisso ver se cada valor é igual e comparar para depois somar e dividir pelo total

Comment: E deveria dar igual quando tem exatamente as mesmas chaves com os mesmos valores ? Ou pode um ter menos chaves que outra desde que não tenha diferentes ?

Comment: Os dois hashmaps terão sempre as mesmas chaves, mas com valores possivelemente diferentes? Ou as chaves podem ser diferentes também?